# jquery click position after css zoom / -webkit-transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, zooming

I have a web application that uses fixed css width. (1280px).

With jquery, I added something like

```
$("html").css("zoom",window["zoomRatio"], "important");
```

as well as `-webkit-transform` and the one for mozilla.

Everything works fine, except I realized that one of my chart with the jquery flot plugin doesn't work (tooltip remained to be triggered at the original position before zoom)

Looking into it, I realized that it is the jquery.bind() that caused the problem.  Is there anyway I can alter the mouseover position?

Basically I am looking for a way to pretend the mouse is at a different position.  I looked for this information online, but I cant find much useful info.

Thanks

Edit (my code for the tooltip)

```
   function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y + 5,
        left: x + 5,
        border: '1px solid #fdd',
        padding: '2px',
        'background-color': '#fee',
        opacity: 0.80
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}

var previousPoint = null;
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
    $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));

    if ($("#enableTooltip:checked").length > 0) {
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                $("#tooltip").remove();
                var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                            item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y);
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;            
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Will `$('body').css` instead of `$('html').css` work? Also, try `$('html, body').css` to select them both.

Comment: thanks. but none of them worked...

Comment: It then seems the solution is going to be with the tooltip since that is not keeping up with the location changes. You didn't show any tooltip markup or code to comment on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your **tooltip** has incoming `x` and `y` values provided for that function, you need to test if a zoom condition is currently `true`.

**Edit:** This is done by creating a new `if statement` with two new variables of `zoomActivated` and `zoomOnset` to work with your existing markup. This if statement will be invoked whenever a zoom condition is true.

**Fragment code example:**

```
function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {

    if(zoomActivated){

        x = x + zoomOnset;
        y = y + zoomOnset;

    }

    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( { ....
```

The above will check to see if `zoomActivated` is Boolean `true` and if so will adjust both `x` and `y` to compensate for the objects position that's affected by the **zoom method**. That variable is set `true` when you are calling your jQuery zoom method, and reset to false when that zoom method has completed/returned to original state.

The global variable `zoomOnset` is based on the current zoom magnitude, assuming that the zoom is for both `x` and `y`. The actual value is a fixed value reflective of the fixed zoom value.

Comment: thanks.  I tried it but I don't think zoomActivated and the zoomOnset are set.

Comment: Also, i believe if it does exist, there is problem with it detecting where the mouse is clicked, rather than where the tooltip shows up

Comment: Those two variable do not exist and is what makes testing to see if zoom condition is true. That said, additional markup needs to be created with my Answer serving as a template to get you there. I did not mention those two variable are new since anybody can tell be looking at the markup you provided. To be sure, I edited my answer to include this obvious assessment.

Comment: ...for example, when `$("html").css("zoom",window["zoomRatio"], "important");` is called then `zoomActivated` is set to `1`.